# Change marker in map

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am struggling with changing the marker in my javascript code. In spite of having referred to numerous examples on the web, none of the solutions seem to work for me. I am a beginner, so please try being patient with me.

`
            {% for data in datadump %}
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng({{data.latitude}},{{data.longitude}});

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: '{{data.locationid}}',
            label: '{{data.observationdate}}',
            icon: "{% static '/darkskymap/img/markers/rocket-15.svg' %}"
        });

        {% endfor %}`
```

I have tried different ways to supplying the image to the marker variable but none seem to work.

Solution N° 1 : Static file path as input to icon parameter like the one in example above.

Solution N° 2 : Relative path as input to icon parameter

```
icon: "/darkskymap/static/darkskymap/img/markers/rocket-15.svg"
```

Solution N° 3 : URL path as input to icon parameter

```
var image = "https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/......./darkskymap/static/darkskymap/img/markers/rocket-15.svg"
icon: image
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, There is nothing wrong with

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: '{{data.locationid}}',
        label: '{{data.observationdate}}',
        icon: "{% static '/darkskymap/img/markers/rocket-15.svg' %}"
    });
```

All you need to do is point it to the right resource. 
Try hosting your icon on a server That points it from the host name. eg https://www.pexels.com/search/car/

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: 'https://www.pexels.com/search/car/'
});
```

Or reconfigure your static folder, so you point it to the right path.